# Tablas de relación en SQL developer

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle-sqldeveloper, modelorelacional

He creado una base de datos para un ejercido sobre un seguro médico, tiene que contener los centros (Pk ciudad i PK dirección), los pacientes(pk DNI)y las pruebas (pk código)de la cual se han creado dos tablas de relación pero estas no contienen la información de las respectivas tablas (Paciente (n) a centro (M)) y (Paciente (n) a Pruebas (1)).
Como puedo hacer para arreglarlo o introducir la información de manera manual? Trato de solucionarlo con SELECT () JOIN (1) JOIN (2) y con CREATE TABLE RELACIÓN … pero ambas dan error

Comment: Intenta con `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Me sale difícil entender tu problema. ¿Tienes las tres tablas, pero olvidaste de crear todas las relaciónes? Para m:n nececitas otra tabla los PKs de las dos tablas afectadas (`CREATE TABLE`). Para 1:n nececitas el PK de la una tabla en la otra (`ALTER TABLE`). Entonces tienes que llenar la nueva tabla y la nueva columna manualmente con `INSERT` y `UPDATE`, porque Oracle todavía no sabe cuales filas tienen una relación con cual otra fila.